# (Kobold2d) Clang Error after upgrading to xcode 4.5

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, compiler-errors, kobold2d

I upgraded to xcode 4.5 and also updated Kobold2d to version 2.0.4 and now I am getting this error when trying to build the project.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Items/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/KTireHoops/../__Kobold2D__/libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSDK/libGoogleAdMobAds.a'
```

Does anyone know what is wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried Project -> Clean? Also check that the file is actually there (it should be but who knows).

Comment: Yes I have checked and the file is there and I have also cleaned several times, but nothing has worked.

Comment: I also have this same project in kobold2d 1.1.2 and it builds just fine.

Comment: Is there some way to make xcode not look for that?

Comment: XCode changes its build folder path every upgrade. It causes this problem every single time. I get it with MailCore. If I find out why its searching a directory I didn't tell it to, I'll let you know.