# Kobold2D Clean Install 'clang: error: no such file or directory'

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, kobold2d

I have just installed Kobold2D and have encountered an error before being able to do an initial build with the 'Hello-Kobold2D' project template.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/olivercooper/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/Kobold'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Test-1/../__Kobold2D__/libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSDK/libGoogleAdMobAds.a'
```

I haven't touched anything, literally just clicked 'Run'.

I am using Xcode 4.5.2, OS X 10.8.

I *have* looked at this question: [(Kobold2d) Clang Error after upgrading to xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589782/kobold2d-clang-error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-5) but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Do these files/folders exist? If not, it might have been an incomplete installation. Downloading the installer again might fix it.

Comment: No they do exist, I'll uninstall and reinstall and report back.

Comment: After reinstalling I tried creating a new project again with a similar title and it had the same error message. However, when I created one with out a space it worked fine, is this just me or a repeatable bug?

Comment: I got this error too with the Chapter 3 Essentials project from Learn cocos2d 2, but then it went away. I swear the clean build didn't fix it, but removing some of the warnings might have helped... There isn't even any call to AdMob stuff in the Chapter 3 code...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To anyone who has the problem, it appears to me that if you have a space in your project name (e.g. 'Kobold2D Test-1') it won't build. You just need to recreate the project with no spaces in the name.